# chartkick chart.js change colour of axis and colour of axis title

Tags: colors, ruby-on-rails-3.2, chart.js, axis-labels, chartkick

In my rails app I added some chart and wanted to change the colours from black (see image).
[image]

Here is the code in my view:

```
<%= line_chart $tweet_per_day, id: "line_chart $tweet_per_day", width: "400px", height: "300px", ytitle: "Tweets count", ytitleFontColor: ["pink", "#F76161"], colors: ["blue", "#76BDD1"], download: "top_hashtags", refresh: 60 %>
```

the chart is getting the right color but the axis title are black so are the axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seem like [chartkick](https://www.chartkick.com/) with [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) has some [limitations](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues/268). So I switch to [google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery).
I removed the chart.js code in my application.html.erb and application.js and replace it with [google chart code](https://www.chartkick.com/#installation).
To change my line chart [this page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options) was helpful.
Below is the working code in my view:

```
<%= line_chart $tweet_day, id:"line_chart $tweet_day",xtitle: "Day of the Week", ytitle: "Tweets Count", colors: ["#C2F4FF"], download: "tweet_day", refresh: 60, 
  library: { 
    vAxis: { baselineColor: "#F76161",  gridlines: {Color: "" }, textStyle: { color: "#76BDD1"}, titleTextStyle: {color: "#F76161"} }, 
    hAxis: { baselineColor: "#F76161" , gridlines: {Color: "" }, textStyle: { color: "#76BDD1"} , titleTextStyle: {color: "#F76161"} } } %>
```

hope it help someone.